# Custom background on Blogger in (post) pages

Tags: blogger

I am trying to make the following modification on Blogger:
When I make a blog post, I want it to have a custom background.
When other users make it, the background should remain default.

I've tried with this code but it doesn't seem to work.

```
<b:if cond='data:displayname == my-user'>
<style type='text/css'>
.foa_bg {
  background-image: url(https://site.github.io/folder/images/covers/image.jpg);
}
</style>
</b:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
<b:if cond='data:post.author == &quot;my-user&quot;'>
<style type='text/css'>
.foa_bg {
  background-image: url(https://site.github.io/folder/images/covers/image.jpg);
}
</style>
</b:if>
```

I'm assuming that *my-user* is your author name on display like it's on your blogger profile.